# Search for / and replace with \/

Tags: sed

This may be simple but I have some text

Aasfdsajdf/safdhglah (as an example)

and I want it to be

Aasfdsajdf\/safdhglah

I have tried multiple sed options but yet find something that gives the correct result.  Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters like `/` and `\` by prefixing them with `\`

```
sed 's/\//\\\//g' <file>
```

You can look [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm) for detailed `sed` guide

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Aasfdsajdf/safdhglah" |sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` utility's `s` ("substitute") command can do this using

```
sed 's#/#\\/#g'
```

So,

```
echo 'Aasfdsajdf/safdhglah' | sed 's#/#\\/#g'
```

would output

```
Aasfdsajdf\/safdhglah
```

The `#` in the `sed` expression are the delimiters that are usually written as `/`.  Since we're dealing with substituting `/` here, we use another delimiter to avoid [the leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

If you're using `bash` and have the string in a variable, then the you may use

```
string='Aasfdsajdf/safdhglah'
printf '%s\n' "${string////\\/}"
```

to get the same output. Here we use `${string//word/replacement}` with `word` being `/` and `replacement` being `\\/` (i.e. a literal `\` and a `/`, just as in the `sed` substitution).

Comment: THank you very much! i didn't know it is possible to switch delimiters

Comment: @Ezwig You may use almost any character as delimiter with the `s` command in `sed`.